# My cat hates me, how do I make him like me now?

Tags: cats

I used to pick up my cat and scare him and do whatever to him when he was a kitten, but now he hates me. I know this is kinda the consequences of my actions but I can't even seem to get near him. Whenever I walk past him in the kitchen he always chases me and jumps at me trying to scratch me, and I only get to pet him without retaliation like once or twice a day.